# Dynamic schema in E-commerce

Tags: e-commerce, atg, broadleaf-commerce

E-commerce websites show different fields for products of different categories. This implies they implement a dynamic schema. What techniques are used for such dynamic schema?

I am aware of Magento using the EAV model. Is there any other option which is used by other frameworks like ATG, Broadleaf, IBM Websphere commerce, etc.?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way of extending products to have category-specific attributes in ATG is to extend the `product` repository item descriptor.

Usually, you would create a new sub-type of product for a category-specific product, and add properties for each category-specific attribute.

For example, you may want to define a "TV Product" sub-type of product where it has a Screen Size attribute

By default, there is only one type of `product`. This fact is represented by the `type` property having no options.

```
<property name="type" data-type="enumerated" column-name="product_type" writable="false" hidden="true"> </property>
```

You can extend that to represent multiple types and sub-types.

```
<property name="type" data-type="enumerated" column-name="product_type" writable="false" hidden="true">
  <option value="tv"/>
  <option value="option2"/>
</property>
```

Then, you can define your sub-type item descriptor as

```
<item-descriptor name="tvProduct" super-type="product" sub-type-value="tv">
  <!-- properties -->
</item-descriptor>
```

And then you can add `property` and `table` elements in your subtype to represent the category-specific properties such as `screenSize`.

There onwards, you can treat a `tvProduct` like any other kind of product. They will show up in any queries etc. for items of type `product` - but when you have an instance of a `tvProduct` it will have an additional `screenSize` property.

Answer (score 0):

In Broadleaf, there are 2 ways to add custom properties:

1. Subclass the existing `ProductImpl` Hibernate entity that corresponds to the BLC_PRODUCT table, putting all of your custom properties in a new MYCOMPANY_PRODUCT table instead. There is a pretty good tutorial on this at http://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/tutorials/core-tutorials/extending-entities-tutorial
2. Most of the Broadleaf entities (like `ProductImpl` and `SkuImpl`) have a Map attribute map attached to them that you can add custom properties to without creating a new table or a new subclass. With the Broadleaf Custom Field module (a commercial module) these new dynamic fields can show up automatically in admin forms